# SQL - displaying row where the next numeric value is also available

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT CAST(year_week AS NUMERIC) as year_week FROM web_details  where location = ''JF'' AND property_id = ''FARM''
```

which produces the following results.

```
YEAR_WEEK
201035
201036
201037
201039
201041
201044
201045
201048
```

What I actually want is to produce a set of results which only displays values if the consecutive value is available - so producing the following results...

```
YEAR_WEEK
201035
201036
201044
```

To add another spanner into the works, the column year_week is not a numeric value so has needed to be converted.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Querying for two Consecutive Rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634666/sql-querying-for-two-consecutive-rows)

Comment: Instead of asking the same question again, without referencing your original question, you could have posted another question asking only for the conversion part.

Comment: sorry... i'd do that next time! thanks

Comment: `+1` for an interesting question, and for responding to comments. Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CAST(year_week AS NUMERIC) as year_week 
FROM 
    web_details wd 
WHERE 
    EXISTS(
        SELECT 
            year_week
        FROM 
            web_details wd2 
        WHERE 
            wd2.year_week = CASE(RIGHT(wd.year_week, 2))
                        WHEN '48' THEN CAST((CAST(LEFT(wd.year_week,4) AS INT) + 1) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '01'
                        ELSE LEFT(wd.year_week,4) + CAST((CAST(RIGHT(wd.year_week,2) AS INT) + 1) AS VARCHAR(2))
                     END
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, my approach is that you calculate another column that contains the next year_week value, and the join it to itself.

```
  WITH myCTE AS (
    SELECT year_week, CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),DATEPART(year,CONVERT(datetime,LEFT(year_week,4)) + (RIGHT(year_week,2) + 1) * 7 )) + RIGHT( '000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(MONTH,CONVERT(datetime,LEFT(year_week,4)) + (RIGHT(year_week,2) + 1) * 7)),2) next_year_week
FROM web_details
WHERE ..........
    )
    SELECT T1.year_week, T2.year_week 
    FROM myCTE T1 
    INNER JOIN myCTE T2 ON T1.next_year_week = T2.year_week
```